# What does the below code do? Is it a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
char[] removechararray=removecharacterstring.toCharArray();

boolean[]  tempBoolean = new boolean[128];

tempBoolean[removechararray[start]]=true;
```

Comment: There's no 2D array in this code.

Comment: where you see 2D? I can see only 1D.

Comment: it simply sets the `tempBoolean` for the `int` representation of the `Char` in the array `removechararray` at a position `start` to  `true`

Answer (score 4):

`reremovechararray[start]` returns and `char` which is casted to `int` and used as index for the `tempBoolean` array.

Example:

```
char[] removechararray="abc".toCharArray();
boolean[]  tempBoolean = new boolean[128];
tempBoolean[removechararray[0]]=true;
```

The above code assigns `true` to the 98 th element of the `tempBoolean` array, because `removechararray[0]` returns an `a` which is casted to its acsii value 97. It's a bit confusing, but you can cast `char` to `int` and backwards and do operations like this:

```
int c = 'b' + 1;
System.out.println(c + " " + (char) c); // output: 99 c
```